# ROS kinetic on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS install error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm a noob to linux and while installing ROS Kinetic on 16.04 LTS encountered this error

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/6c611bce795230cb8a4b00257cd19ce8

Kindly help.
Thank you

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263434/ros-kinetic-on-my-ubuntu-16.04-lts-install-error/) by [Pranav_Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/30680/pranav_kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like dpkg is having issues independent of ROS, I would try the steps listed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325513/getting-dependency-issues-on-configuring-dpkg and then following the error messages from there if problems persist.

---

Originally posted by [Dale McConachie](https://answers.ros.org/users/30596/dale-mcconachie/) with karma: 91 on 2017-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1